# In Django, how do I get an instance of an unsaved inline object in the form init method?

Tags: python, django, forms, instance

Let's say I have the following form:

```
class MyInlineItemForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyInlineItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        obj = kwargs.get('instance', '')
```

`obj` will come back with the instance of any saved items.  However, if an inline item is unsaved (i.e. because there were errors), this comes back with no instance, just a bunch of data floating around in `kwargs`.

Now `kwargs` does come back with a "prefix" key that would allow me to grab some of the items I may need, but I'm a little surprised that there is no clean built-in way to access the unsaved item as an object.

So question is, if there is no "instance" key in `kwargs` by which to access an unsaved inline item in object form, what is a good clean way to access this item?  Or do I just need to create one manually?

The problem I'm working on requires that certain fields be populated dynamically during form generation based on certain other fields, so I need to be able to access those other fields.

Answer (score 0):

When you init your form, you should pass object instance in this way.

```
MyInlineItemForm(instance=object_instance)
```

Then, you can access to instance object through `kwargs`.